# How do I fix this wall to prep for Backsplash?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, backsplash

How do I repair these two parts of the wall? We recently got our countertops replaced, and we they took out the old pieces of granite from the wall it caused this.

We would like to repair then paint the wall on the left. On that back wall, we would like to repair and then put backsplash.

If you could please help with both parts of the question.

[image: Kitchen Wall]

Comment: It depends...is the new backsplash gonna be the same height as the old?  Are you gonna be repainting the walls?

Answer (score 1):

Scrape, sand, add joint compound. The next day, sand again, apply primer. Next day paint.

Where you are installing a backsplash, just scrape and install backsplash on top.